# How to download converted HTML file in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on codebeautify.org site,
in which I want to convert excel to HTML file. I've converted that but I can't download the file.

```
public function convertHTML(){

    $fileName=$this->input->post('fileName');

    $file_ext = end(explode('.',$fileName));


    if($file_ext!="xlsx"){
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(LOCAL_UPLOAD_PATH.$fileName);
    for($s=0; $s<count($data->sheets); $s++) {
    echo "<b><u>Sheet Name</u> :- ".$data->boundsheets[$s]['name']."</b><hr>";
    echo $data->dump(false,false,$s);
    echo "<hr>";
    }
    $fh = fopen(LOCAL_UPLOAD_PATH.$fileName, 'a');
    fclose($fh);
    unlink(LOCAL_UPLOAD_PATH.$fileName);
    }
    else{
        $this->convertXLSXtoHTML($fileName);
    }

}
```

Now I want to download it. How can I do it?

Comment: now i want to download that how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **download instead of Show** in the browser there are some options, but to be honest, I prefer show the file, because the options are not a very good user experience, and the last one not always is possible:

- Option 1: Insert the excel in a `.zip`
- Option 2: The browser (some of them) has an option which ask to the users if they want to show or download the file, the problem with this is that option is not working only in your page.
- Option 3: add in the `.htacces` the next code to force the browser to download some type of files:

  `<FilesMatch "\.(?i:xlxs)$">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  </FilesMatch>`